# Powershell - Get-ADOBJECCT Trying to show a subset of values of a custom class

Tags: active-directory, powershell, powershell-v5.0

Here is my script that works great:

```
Select-object -Property name,@{Name="bofaamlmember";Expression={$_.bofaamlmember -join ";"}},@{Name="canonicalName";Expression={$_.canonicalName -join ";"}} | Sort-object bofaamlmember | Export-Csv "C:\Users\nbkn4wz\documents\Scripts\bofaamlmemberExt.csv"
```

The script returns the values that I requested:

```
         **Name**               **Bofaamlmember**
RG-AdministratorsMembers    CN=CSW_IIS_Support_SvcAcct_BUSP_AP,OU=Common,etc....
```

The issue I am having is within the bofaamlmember attribute there are members of that attribute:

Example:
[Attribute Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFWOs.png)

I want to be able to export just the members.

I don't want to use the CN, its too much info. I want just the value(s) that are listed in that box.

Comment: Are you saying you only want the first field of each CN?

Comment: That's correct.  If its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet should be close, but I cannot test. It splits the bofaamlmember on commas and selects the first element (0) then splits on = and takes the second (1)

```
;Expression={(($_.bofaamlmember).split(",")[0]).split("=")[1] -join ";"}
```

(May need one more set of (...) at the beginning and before join)

Comment: This worked pretty good, but we have accounts like:  Type S\M346. The output of this script gives me the Type S\ but nothing after it.